# Keycloak not sending verification email when REST API is used to create user. How to achieve this?

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

There is a similar question around ([Keycloak - Verify user's email using Rest API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62007767/keycloak-verify-users-email-using-rest-api)) which does not answer my question.

When setting `Verify email` to `true` in the realm settings and registering a user through Keycloak an email is sent to the user. The template used is `email-verification.ftl`.

When having the same realm setting but creating a user through the REST API `POST /{realm}/users` the email is **not** sent. There is a REST API method `PUT /{realm}/users/{id}/send-verify-email` available, but it uses a different email template `executeActions.ftl`.

My expectation is Keycloak to send out an email 'normally' when the realm setting requires to verify your email. No matter whether you use the REST API or the UI.

Is there any fix/workaround to this?

Comment: Can you show an example of json user reprensentation you have posted to `/{realm}/users` ? Did you populate the 'emailVerified' field ?

Comment: @TacheDeChoco I am using a Java library. Not sure how this would make a difference. The field you are mentioning will set the email to being verified. Not what I want. I want Keycloak to send out an email for verification on sign up.

Comment: @MoritzSchmitzv.Hülst have you solved this? I am experiencing the same issue

Comment: I didn't. I opened a ticket with RedHat though: https://issues.redhat.com/browse/KEYCLOAK-18455